# Is it possible to run RMI server in tomcat?

Tags: java, rmi

I have two tomact instances, running on `Tomcat 7` (call it `tomcat 1`, `tomcat 2`). I need to arrange distributed computation. The server `tomcat 1` should invoke some method on `tomcat 2`'s VM.

Is it even possible to do? I know that Tomcat is a servlet container. Does it support such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you don't run RMI on Tomcat. You must run rmiregistry on server and connect to this registry form your Tomcat's. Your application should implement interface extent Remote, and its implementation like in general RMI application. It could be a little hard, because you must register your service twice once for tomcat 1, and second for tomcat 2, it could be done via configuration or hard coded.

Maybe you should consider provide your RMI Server as java application, and invoke there method from Tomcat or read about JMS, it is more common solution today than RMI.

Comment: You have some evidence for that last assertion? And why does he have to register his service twice?

Comment: Twice, because we have to bind Remote implementation on tomcat 1 for tomcat 2 under name1 and must bind the implementation on tomcat 2 for tomcat 1 under name2. I described example if we want to invoke remote procedure from both tomcat each other. I am not expert in RMI and this i solution tested by some time ago, maybe it could be bind under one service name. I have no evidence, it's just my observations of what is required in the job market and what i use at work.

Comment: None of this makes sense. There only one Registry per host. If the Tomcats are in the same host you only need to bind once, and if they're in different hosts you can't bind to a remote Registry at all, at least not without special measures. One working solution by a non-expert doesn't justify saying how it 'must' be done.

Answer (score 1):

A RMI server can be run in Tomcat, a good place to start it up is a ServletContextListener.

With LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port) you don't even need an external rmiregistry.

Nowadays people would use an HTTP based protocol like REST to host a service in a server like Tomcat, but RMI still works and is way faster and easier to use than HTTP.